# curl command to tarball ALL organizations repos thru API

Tags: api, github, curl

Was making a bash script to backup organization's repos (private included) convert them into a tar file and then send off to s3 bucket.

```
curl -H "Authorization: token {PAT}" -L https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/tarball/main > main.tar.gz
```

When I do this command with one single repo it works, but my task was to have it grab all 100+ repos in the organization. Any thoughts of what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any API from GitHub to provide your desired HTTP call out of the box.

You can try to create a Bash/PowerShell script to:

1. List the organization:

> ```
> curl \
>   -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
>   -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
>   https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/repos
> ```

(reference: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-organization-repositories)

2. Take the result and convert it to an array.
3. For each element in the array, run your command:

> curl -H "Authorization: token {PAT}" -L
> [https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/tarball/main](https://api.github.com/repos/%7Borg%7D/tarball/main) > main.tar.gz